# EF invalidate a single entity cache

Tags: entity-framework

Is there a way to invalidate a single entity such that the next time I ask for it, EF goes to the database for it?

Please note that I am not asking for any Refresh-Reload method. I just need to invalidate the cache such that in case this entity is needed again EF is forced to go to the database (only in case it is needed).

This is my concrete scenario (just if you have a couple of advises to me).

Lets suppose that I have a relationship in which a parent can have many children and the parent has properties that are summarized data about the children, e.g., Order.TotalQuantity.

If I insert, update, delete an OrderItem, I do it using a store procedure (that is mapped to these operations in EF). The aforementioned store procedures insert, update, and delete the OrderItem, but also update certain fields of the parent Order.

How am I supposed to handle this in EF? Do I "invalidate" the Order? If I ask for the Order before a call to SaveChanges the order would return with the wrong TotalQuantity anyway....

Thank you so much!!!

Comment: what you trying to say here?  the entities Order and OrderItem have a relationship? also you meant to do CRUD operation in store procedure and EF ??

Comment: Yes. An order has many order items and I use store procedures to insert, update, and delete. I actually said it:)

Comment: My proble is that when I insert one order item I also modify some properties of the order and I need a way to reflect that in my model.